# PowerShell adding value to a custom object property

Tags: powershell, csv, psobject

I am new in PowerShell, and I am a bit lost, I have created a new PSobject that stores Dates and the Hash of a file and that data is stored in a .csv file. My problem lies in trying to update the information when the Hash of the file changes. I would not want to overwrite the file, but add the new information. Below is what I have done so far and the error I get. I hope someone can clarify the problem that I have. Thanks in advance

```
function GetFileHash {
    $wc = [System.Net.WebClient]::new()
    $settingsObject = Get-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot\config.json | ConvertFrom-Json
    try {
        Get-FileHash -InputStream($wc.OpenRead($settingsObject.pdfUrl))
    }
    catch {
        return $null
    }
}

function CheckforUpdate {
    $fileHash = GetFileHash
    if ($null -eq $fileHash) {
        "Some error occured. The error was: " + $Error[0]
        return
    }
    $csvPath = Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath "hashInfo.csv"
    $checkDate = Get-Date
    if ((Test-Path $csvPath) -eq $false) {
        $CSVObject = New-Object PSobject
        $CSVObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "CheckDate" -Value $checkDate.DateTime
        $CSVObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "LastknowHash" -Value $fileHash.Hash
        $CSVObject | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $csvPath
    } else {
        Write-Host "The csv file exist"
        $csvData = @(import-csv $csvPath)
        $onlineHash = $fileHash.Hash
        $lastKnowHash = $csvData | Where-Object {$_.Value -eq $onlineHash}
        if ($lastKnowHash -ne $onlineHash) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                CheckDate = $checkDate.DateTime
                LastknowHash = $fileHash.Hash
            } | Export-Csv -Path $csvPath -Append -NoTypeInformation
        }
    }
}

CheckforUpdate
```

**Here is the error:**

> The CheckDate property was not found for this object. Make sure that the property exists and can be set.
> The LastKnowHash property was not found for this object. Make sure that the property exists and can be set.

Comment: You're using quite a lot of undefined variables..

Comment: Did you mean `$CSVObject` instead of `$csvData`? Because `$csvData` isn't assigned anywhere in the code sample.

Comment: ```$csvData``` is where I import the csv file again.

Comment: The code sample is still incomplete. How are `$fileHash` and `$onlineHash` set?

Comment: If I got it right you create an object with two properties, export it to CSV and re-import it to compare it against the same values you used to create the object. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: @Olaf I want to store the new Hash inside the Object along with a timestamp when the script is executed, but I have the errors I mention above. Thanks for your time

Comment: @zett42 The ```$fileHash``` come from another function ```$fileHash = GetFileHash``` and after I do ```$onlineHash = $fileHash.Hash``` I hope now is more clear, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumed there already is a CSV file in the folder with the given headers you could replace your second function with something like this:

```
$csvPath = Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath 'hashInfo.csv'
$csvData = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath

$LastFileHash = ($csvData | Select-Object -Last 1).LastknowHash
$CurrentFileHash = (GetFileHash).Hash
if ($LastFileHash -ne $CurrentFileHash) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        CheckDate    = Get-Date
        LastknowHash = $CurrentFileHash
    } |
    Export-Csv -Path $csvPath -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

It will read the existing CSV file, take the last file hash and compare it against the current one you get with your function `GetFileHash`. If they're different the current file hash is written to the CSV file along with the current time stamp.

Comment: The above error is no longer displayed, but every time I run the script it writes the same Hash (it has not changed) over and over again and what I need it to write to the **csv** file if the Hash has changed.

Comment: You did not show in your question where you create the hash. That's what we meant when we claimed that your code sample is incomplete.

Comment: I just updated the code, I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance